# in mongodb the $or operator takes precedence over a simple equal (key: value)?

Tags: mongodb

I wonder if it will evaluate the parent within the '$ or' statement or the one (key / value), what takes precedence or what is the expected behavior and why?

```
db.collection.find({ 
    parent: '2kzW57uhwthPFNyB9',
    access: null,
    '$or': [ { owner: 'PBjjLpK9fQi4qyTd4' },
      { parent: { $in: ['2kzW57uhwthPFNyB9', '6we357uhwthPFwerr'] } } ]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  parent: '2kzW57uhwthPFNyB9',//condition1
  access: null,//condition2
  '$or': [
    {
      owner: 'PBjjLpK9fQi4qyTd4'//condition 3.0
    },
    {
      parent: {//condition 3.1
        $in: [
          '2kzW57uhwthPFNyB9',
          '6we357uhwthPFwerr'
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It is `and` condition when you specify comma separated conditions in find.

You have 4 conditions as I named above.

It works like `condition1 AND condition 2 AND (condition 3.0 OR condition 3.1)`

So no precedence.

Comment: Which condition will be evaluated first in OR? 3.0 or 3.1